# Show that $\frac{(-1)^{n}}{\left(\ln(n)+(-1)^{n}\right)^{2}}=\frac{(-1)^{n}}{\ln^{2}(n)}+v_n\quad \left( v_n\sim -\frac{2}{\ln^{3}(n)} \right) $

Tags: asymptotics, taylor-expansion

> I would like to show that :
>   $$\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{\left(\ln(n)+(-1)^{n}\right)^{2}}=\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{\ln^{2}(n)}+v_n\quad \left( v_n\sim -\dfrac{2}{\ln^{3}(n)} \right)\\  $$
>   by starting from the left side and get the right side

**My proof:**

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{\left(\ln(n)+(-1)^{n}\right)^{2}}&= \dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{\ln^{2}(n)}\left(1+\dfrac{(-1)^n}{\ln(n)} \right)^{-2} \\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{\ln^{2}(n)}\left(1-2\dfrac{(-1)^n}{\ln(n)} +\mathcal{O}\left( \dfrac{1}{\ln(n)} \right) \right)\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{\ln^{2}(n)}-\dfrac{2}{\ln^{3}(n)} +\mathcal{O}\left( \dfrac{1}{\ln^{3}(n)} \right) \\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{\ln^{2}(n)}+v_n\quad \left( v_n\sim -\dfrac{2}{\ln^{3}(n)} \right)\\
\end{align*}

$$-\dfrac{2}{\ln^{3}(n)} +\mathcal{O}\left( \dfrac{1}{\ln^{3}(n)} \right) \sim -\dfrac{2}{\ln^{3}(n)}$$
since :

- $$\left| \dfrac{-\dfrac{2}{\ln^{3}(n)} +\mathcal{O}\left( \dfrac{1}{\ln^{3}(n)} \right) }{-\dfrac{2}{\ln^{3}(n)}}\right|=\left|1+\dfrac{\mathcal{O}\left( \dfrac{1}{\ln^{3}(n)} \right)}{-\dfrac{2}{\ln^{3}(n)}} \right|\leq 1+\dfrac{1}{2}$$ i can't prove that goes to 1 when n tend to infinity

**Update:**

Could someone  please prove $$-\dfrac{2}{\ln^{3}(n)} +\mathcal{O}\left( \dfrac{1}{\ln^{3}(n)} \right) \sim -\dfrac{2}{\ln^{3}(n)}$$  Is it true that : $$-\dfrac{2}{\ln^{3}(n)} +\mathcal{o}\left( \dfrac{1}{\ln^{3}(n)} \right) \sim -\dfrac{2}{\ln^{3}(n)} \implies -\dfrac{2}{\ln^{3}(n)} +\mathcal{O}\left( \dfrac{1}{\ln^{3}(n)} \right) \sim -\dfrac{2}{\ln^{3}(n)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Replace $\mathcal O\Bigl(\dfrac1{\ln n}\Bigr)$, which is not false, but doesn't bring any information here, with the correct
$ \;o\Bigl(\dfrac1{\ln n}\Bigr)$.
You'll get 
$$-\frac{2}{\ln^{3}n} +\mathcal{o}\Bigl( \frac{1}{\ln^{3}n} \Bigr) \sim -\frac{2}{\ln^{3}n}$$
by definition.

Comment: could you elaborate ? could you prove $-\dfrac{2}{\ln^{3}(n)} +\mathcal{O}\left( \dfrac{1}{\ln^{3}(n)} \right) \sim -\dfrac{2}{\ln^{3}(n)}$ and if $$-\dfrac{2}{\ln^{3}(n)} +\mathcal{o}\left( \dfrac{1}{\ln^{3}(n)} \right) \sim -\dfrac{2}{\ln^{3}(n)} \implies -\dfrac{2}{\ln^{3}(n)} +\mathcal{O}\left( \dfrac{1}{\ln^{3}(n)} \right) \sim -\dfrac{2}{\ln^{3}(n)}$$   and what you said is by definition is it come from $$u_n{\underset {n\to +\infty}{\sim}}v_n  \implies u_n+v_n{\underset {n\to +\infty}{=}}o(v_n)$$

Comment: By definition, $\;u_n\sim v_n\iff u_n=v_n+o(v_n)\;$ (if $\;v_n\ne 0$, this is of course  the same as $\;\lim u_n/v_n=1$).

Comment: Could you please prove $$-\dfrac{2}{\ln^{3}(n)} +\mathcal{O}\left( \dfrac{1}{\ln^{3}(n)} \right) \sim -\dfrac{2}{\ln^{3}(n)}$$  Is it true that : $$-\dfrac{2}{\ln^{3}(n)} +\mathcal{o}\left( \dfrac{1}{\ln^{3}(n)} \right) \sim -\dfrac{2}{\ln^{3}(n)} \implies -\dfrac{2}{\ln^{3}(n)} +\mathcal{O}\left( \dfrac{1}{\ln^{3}(n)} \right) \sim -\dfrac{2}{\ln^{3}(n)}$$

Comment: I can't, because it's false in general. What I meant is only  that $g(n)=o(f(n)\implies g(n)=\mathcal O(f(n))$, which brings no information as $f(n)=\mathcal O(f(n))$.